# Ticket System discord.js check for ticket

Tags: discord.js

My Ticket System is pretty much done. My only problem left is to check whether a person already has a ticket. Unfortunately I don't know how to check that. I mostly find answers with a database but I would like to avoid that right now.

My Ticket System:

```js
        case 'ticket':
        case 'Ticket':


            var guild = client.guilds.cache.get('897417868633940028')
            guild.channels.create(message.member.displayName + 's-ticket', {
                type: 'text',
                topic: message.author.id + '-ticket',
                parent: '897771652451678268',
                permissionOverwrites: [
                    {
                        id: message.author.id,
                        allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL', 'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY', 'EMBED_LINKS', 'ATTACH_FILES'],
                    },
                    {
                        id: message.guild.roles.everyone,
                        deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                    },
                    {
                        id: "897772395368583178",
                        allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                    },
                ],
            })

            let created = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("Ticket-System")
                .setThumbnail('png')
                .setDescription(`Hello, '${message.member.displayName}'. You're ticket is created.`)
                .setColor("GREY")
                .setTimestamp()


            message.channel.send({ embeds: [created] });

            let newchannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === `${message.member.displayName}s-ticket`);
            message.guild.channels.cache.get(`${newchannel}`)

            break;


        case 'close':

            if (!message.channel.name.includes("-ticket")) return message.channel.send("You can't delete that channel, nice try")
            message.channel.delete()

            break;



            case 'rename':

            var rename = message.content.slice(" rename" .length);
            if(!message.channel.name.includes("-ticket")) return message.channel.send("You can't rename this channel!")
            if(!message.member.permissions.has(Discord.Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_ROLES)) return message.channel.send("You can't do that!")
            message.channel.setName(rename + '-ticket')

        
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting the topic to `userID-ticket`, you can check the channel topic. The channel may not be cached so using [`GuildChannelManager#fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) might help.

```js
await guild.channels.fetch()
if (guild.channels.cache.some(c => c.topic?.startsWith(message.author.id)) {
  //User has a ticket already
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error now: 

C:\Discord Bots\Bot v13\index.js:436
            if (guild.channels.cache.some(c => c.topic.startsWith(message.author.id))) return {       
                                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined

Comment: @IneedHelp I edited it. Some channels don't have topics

Comment: It's not working. I can still create as many tickets as i like